# How do I extract Array string from JSON with PHP and form a table?

Tags: php, html, json

I have a JSON like:

```
{
   "id": 30,
   "output": {
      "status": "ok",
      "data": {
        "text/plain": "Array({\"a\":\"orange\",\"b\":\"fruit\"},{\"a\":\"apple\",\"b\":\"fruit\"}, {\"a\":\"pineapple\",\"b\":\"fruit\"})\n"
       }
    }
}
```

The value of "text/plain" is my actual result, which I want to parse in a table format in HTML, Like:

```
|---------|---------|
|   a     |    b    |
|---------|---------|
|orange   |  fruit  |
|apple    |  fruit  |
|pineapple|  fruit  |
|---------|---------|
```

but I am unable to extract it in a proper way.

Need Help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is your `data` some kind of serialised thing (looks like output from `print_r`) rather than just being part of the JSON?

Comment: yeah, you are right, this output is the result of "println", I got this json from `spark-submit` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround code, and it will work only for the specified example. I have not tested for any other sample input.

```
<?php
    $x = '{
          "id": 30,
          "output": {
             "status": "ok",
             "data": {
               "text/plain": "Array({\"a\":\"orange\",\"b\":\"fruit\"},{\"a\":\"apple\",\"b\":\"fruit\"}, {\"a\":\"pineapple\",\"b\":\"fruit\"})\n"
              }
           }
       }';
    $y = json_decode($x);
    $z = (array) $y->output->data;
    $p = $z['text/plain'];
    $p = str_replace('Array(', '[', $p);
    $p = str_replace(')', ']', $p);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($p);
    print_r(json_decode($p));
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```